# Scroll to first Form Error Using LiveValidation

Tags: javascript, forms, scroll, livevalidation, eloqua

I am looking for a way to scroll to the first error using only the [LiveValidation 1.3 JavaScript library](https://img.en25.com/i/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js). I see examples online of how to do it in general, but nothing for LiveValidation. This is for an Eloqua form that uses the LiveValidation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own issue. The code did not work when targeting ".LV_invalid:first" by itself, but when I target the ".parent('p')" it now works fine.

```
  var form = $('form');
  $(form).on('submit', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".LV_invalid:first").parent('p').offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
```